# array argument passing: copy on write is implicit?

Tags: php

I wonder about the performance of array argument passing: it's worth to add the 'pass by reference' specifier to the argument to avoid the copy of the data, or such micro optimization is already implicitly implemented by the runtime ?

Let's say I have an array indexed by a not sequential key (of course). I've written this helper

```
function position_in_array($needle, &$haystack) {
    $k = array_search($needle, $haystack);
    return $k === false ? false : array_search($k, array_keys($haystack));
}
```

What I can see [from documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) make me think that argument array *copy* could really be *copy on write*.

In case such hypothesis turns out to be correct, I will remove the 'by reference' specifier.

Comment: Just remove your `&`; PHP is _smarter_ than it looks at the first sight.

Comment: @AlmaDo: thanks, indeed I was incline to follow your 'line of tought'. But, the point is, how much smarter ?

Comment: It's smarter like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YZIBWQr_yk)

Comment: @AlmaDo: I don't understand spoken English enough to say if Antony did understood my problem :-). And of course, it doesn't answer my doubt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PHP is a dynamic, loosely typed language, that uses copy-on-write and reference counting.

Yes, PHP uses copy on write.

You don't need to specify the & unless you need to modify the argument passed to your function (which implies you don't want copy on write, but real reference)

As N.B commented, [it's taken from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php), in the introduction to variables.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind to add an hint from where you took the citation ?

Comment: @CapelliC [Taken from the manual, introduction to variables](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php)

Comment: Thanks again. I jumped in PHP from WordPress development, so many things to learn. I missed this one in the large documentation...